# Toilet is running but the flapper is clean and intact

Tags: toilet

I have a toilet that is running, probably once every ten to fifteen minutes.  I hear a quiet dripping sound within the tank.  I understand that the most common problem associated with these events is a flapper that needs cleaning or replacement.  Mine is pretty new and looks clean.  I've now just cleaned it again.  I've shut off the water to the tank.  After I flushed, only a small amount of water remains at the base of the tank, and I'm still hear the dripping sound.

I'm not sure what the piece is called, but should I perhaps be caulking around the piece that the flapper inserts into?  Or maybe I'll just replace the flapper again?

I appreciate any help anyone can offer,

Alex

Comment: It sounds like water is going into the overflow tube.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few places where the flap valve/overflow tube assembly could be leaking. Check for loose parts, but *don't over-tighten* or you'll crack plastic parts or, worse, the porcelain!

[image: Flap valve & overflow tube assembly]

- There are bolts holding the tank to the bowl, with rubber washers to prevent leakage. Make sure the bolts and nuts are tight -- sometimes, the tank will shift, loosening the bolts.
- The flap valve seat (often part of the overflow tube assembly) also has a rubber washer underneath, and a foam rubber collar. If the valve seat is loose, the tank must be removed to tighten the large-diameter nut.
- Check that the overflow tube is not cracked.
- Check that the flap valve and seat are clean and have no splits or cracks.

See the [City of Denver's tips](https://www.denverwater.org/residential/efficiency-tip/repair-leaky-toilet) on fixing leaks.